# define quote process in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have this couple of lines that I'm running on drracket,
I can't understand the output

```
> (define 'a 5)
> 'b
. . ..\..\Program Files\Racket\share\pkgs\drracket\drracket\private\rep.rkt:1088:24: b: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> '0
5
```

is quote redefined?
why 'b isn't working and '0 is 5?

Comment: This "confusion" comes from the fact that `'` is just a reader macro and that the implementation only see `(quote b)`. Unlike other languages you can redefine keywords like `quote` which basically makes the syntax `'` unavailable for the rest of the session. To define a variable `a` you do `(define a 5)` and as expected `a ; ==> 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, symbols are atomic values. They cannot be treated like variables.

Anyway, your first line expands to:

```
(define (quote a) 5)
```

which is shorthand for defining functions in racket. So yes, you are redefining `quote`.

When you try to run `'b`, you're running `(quote b)`, where it expects a variable `b` to have some value, which is does not. That's why you receive the error, `cannot reference an identifier before its definition`.

When you try to run `'0`, you're running `(quote 0)`. 0 is a valid value, and it becomes the value for `a` in your new function. So, the function evaluates as normal, and returns 5.

In other words, it's not just 0 that is a valid argument.

```
> (define 'a 5)
> (define b 12345)
> 'b
5
> '0
5
> '123454321
5
```

---

Check out the [Racket documentation on symbols](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/symbols.html). Symbols don't contain values; they *are* values. You'll want to use variables instead (`(define a 5)`).

Comment: ಠ_ಠ referring to  a valid value for the argument 'a', how can you know what is the type that quote expect? when I defined the symbol a I created a lambda that return the value of 5 or added to the global-environment the value to quote?

Comment: You redefined `quote` to be a lambda that takes one argument and returns 5. So, assuming you're using untyped racket, any value is fine. When I said "valid value," I just meant you can't, for example, try to call the function with an undefined variable. That's what happened when you tried to run `'b`.